# Mongoose.connect doesn't create database if not exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new on NodeJs, I'm learning how to connect to mongodb using NodeJS with Mongoose library. As I know, when I connect to database with a name, if this database with that name doesn't exist, then mongoose will create it automatically, but it's not being created with me.
Here is my code:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/mongo-test", {useNewUrlParser: true})
.then(() => console.log("Connected"))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

mongoose version: `^5.2.5`

Comment: Try to add some collection and document :)

Comment: databases are created on first write operation. connect is not the one.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but you also need to create a record so that it creates the database.
Only specifying the database name on the connection string isn't enough apparently.

Cheers

Comment: This is the correct answer. I have observed this behaviour before - simply opening a database in Mongo does not create it; you have to add a document.

Answer (score 12):

Pedro is right, when you save your first document in the database, mongoose will create the database and the collection for this document.

The name of the database will be the name specified in the connection, in this case **myapp**:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/myapp');
```

Mongoose Documentation: [Connections](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html)

And mongoose creates the collection with a **plural name**.

If you have a model with Tank name, the collection name will be **tanks**:

```
var schema = new mongoose.Schema({ name: 'string', size: 'string' });
var Tank = mongoose.model('Tank', schema);
```

> The first argument is the singular name of the collection your model
>   is for. Mongoose automatically looks for the plural version of your
>   model name. Thus, for the example above, the model Tank is for the
>   **tanks** collection in the database.

Mongoose Documentation: [Model](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html)

Answer (score 0):

Without defining the model, I don't think we can create a new database in Mongoose.

For those facing similar issues->
If you're following MVC architecture, please import the schema/model from the source where database Schema/Models are created, this would solve the issue, or create Schema model in this file itself similar to below:

Sample code to create in the same file for solving such issues:

```
// Import mongoose

const mongoose = require('mongoose')

// Create Schema - ignore if you've already defined.

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: {type:String}, lastName: {type:String}
})

// Then connect this Schema with Model

const userModel = mongoose.model('modelNameHere', userSchema)

// Then connect with database as the above code.
```